# Jenkins (Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build)

Tags: jenkins, smtp, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins isn't able to send emails out to users who broke the build. I have ticked the "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build" box.

The Jenkins server i have is able to send out emails (i've set up SMTP settings). Under the "E-mail Notification" i can specify the person by email and it will send out an email to that person.

I've also ticked "Allow sending to unregistered users" in the configure options.

I'm looking at the console output and it's not sending any command that would allow it to get the email of the person who last committed "git log". It's just sending an email out to "noreply@github.build.company.com"

I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working, i am a very much new starter to jenkins so i am not familiar with start up scripts that jenkins uses. I am only comfortable with the config.xml (forgotten password) and the browser user of jenkins.

```
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk ba6ee9f6c7bc98da7aa3caa77b15a5ebcea14639 # timeout=10
[sandbox_python] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins9151174402241259361.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox_python>python run_python.py 
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_python.py", line 2, in <module>
    dsfafafddasfadsf
NameError: name 'dsfafafddasfadsf' is not defined

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox_python>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: noreply@github.build.company.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've still being digging. The email is coming from "noreply@github.build.company.com" and it's being send to "noreply@github.build.company.com" as well. Don't know what the fix is

Comment: What type of trigger do you use? What are parameters available in your job?

Comment: I'm using Poll SCM and polling it every minute.

The only thing i'm doing is a batch command---echo "hello world"--- When i want it to fail i send the cmd like ---ech dfaf---- to make it fail